# Mysql char search vs integer

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'abcd';
```

Table has lots of rows (1'000'000'000 or more)

If instead of field = 'abcd' i use something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'abcd' AND other_field = 300;
```

, Where 300 is a number that depends on 'abcd' (f(abcd) => 300), will the query run faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Search time when using unique indexes**
MySQL uses BTree indexes.
This means that a unique row is found in log(n) time.
If you search in 65536 rows, it will take max 16 comparisons to find the row, assuming a fully balanced tree.
If you search in 1,000,000,000 it will take 30 comparisons to find the row, assuming a fully balanced tree and unique values.

If you search on a unique key, it makes very little sense to add extra tests.

**Search time using non-unique indexes**
If you search on a non-unique tree, the search time will be fast, but of course the resultset will include more than 1 row, and the query time goes up as the number of rows grows.
Provided that MySQL deems it useful to use an index, the initial key will be found in very few tests.

However the real time is spend going though the rows that match.

Comment: Hm, I agree with all you said. But is there any (minor or major) difference if one field is `VARCHAR(255)` and the other is `INT` ?

Comment: Not really as explained, as long as the tree is reasonally balanced (usually the case) the number of tests is too small to make the substantial difference in test time between a varchar(255) and an int count. That time is drowned out by all the other factors.